# I'm not sure if I'm calling .html and .json files correctly from .js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

So I'm new to Javascript, CSS and HTML and I'm working on an admittedly ambitious project. At this point lets call it a glorified task manager. I've managed to cobble this together from books and online resources. Right now I'm just trying to flesh out the UI and trying to get the main html file to talk to a .js file which talks to another .html file, and .json file. I haven't bothered with the CSS yet. I figured I can do that after I get it to work a little. Here's the code that I think is relevant.

The Main HTML (usetime.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>UseTime</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="jq-load.html">HOME</a>
            <a href="jq-load.html2">PROFILE</a>
            <a href="jq-load.html4">MANAGE TASKS</a>
            <a href="usetime.html">TIME TABLE</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="third">
                <div id="event">
                    <a id="class1" href="class1.html"><img src="" alt="class1" /> Class 1 </a>
                    <a id="class2" href="class2.html"><img src="" alt="class2" /> Class 2 </a>
                    <a id="class3" href="class3.html"><img src="" alt="class3" /> Class 3 </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <div id="sessions"> Select a Class from the left </div>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <div id="details"> Details </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </section>
    <!-- content -->

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/example.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the .js file that's supposed to handle everything(example.js):

```
$(function () { //when the DOM is ready
    var times; //declare global variable
    $.ajax({ //set up request
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { //before requesting data
            if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { //if supported
                xhr.overrideMimeType("applicaition/json"); // set MIME to prevent errors
            }

        }
    });
    //funciton that colleges data from the json file
    fucntion loadTimetable() { //decalre function
        $.getJSON('data/example.json') //try to collect json data
            .done(function (data) { //if succesful
                times = data; //store in variable

            }).fail(fuction() { //if a problem: show message
                $('#event').html('Sorry! we couldnt load your time table at the moment');
            });
    }

    loadTimetable(); //call the function

    //CLICK ON TEH EVENT TO LOAD A TIME TABLE
    $('#content').on('click', '#event a', funciton(e) { //user clicks on place
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading page
        var loc = this.id.toUpperCase(); //get value of id attr

        var newContent = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < times[loc].length; i++) { // loop through sessions
            newContent += '<li><span class = "time">' + times[loc][i].time + '</span>';
            newContent += < a href = "descriptions.html#';
            newContent += times[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
            newContent += times[loc][i].title + '</a></li>';
        }

        $('#sessions').html('<ul>' + newContent + '</ul>'); // Display Time

        $('#event a.current').removeClass('current'); // update selected link
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $('#details').text('');

    });

    //CLICK ON A SESSION TO LEAD THE DESCRIPTION

    $('#content').on('click', '#sessions li a', funciton(e) { //click on session
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent loading
        var fragment = this.href //title is in href

        fragment = fragment.replace('#', ' #'); //Add Space before #
        $('#details').load(fragment); //to load info

        $('#sessions a.current').removeClass('current'); //update selected
    });

    //CLICK ON PRIMARY NAVIGATION
    $('nav a').on('click', function (e) { //click on nav
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading
        var url = this.href //get UR: to load

        $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $('#container').remove(); //remove old
        $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('slow'); // add new

    });
});
```

Additionally there is an example.json that just has a few lines and I have jquery 3.2.1.slim in the same 'usetime' folder

I'm stumped, any help will be super appreciated. Thanks

edit(I wasn't very clear with my question): well when I run the first usetime html code (which should be executing the other stuff) all that i see is the content from the usetime html. I'm not sure what's wrong or how to fix this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are the problems you are facing *specifically*? Is *any of it working* (e.g. you click on `#content` and it fires off the `$('#content').on('click', function(){});` event handler? Have you checked for errors in the console? Is jQuery loading?

Comment: In the JavaScript, there are two misspellings (in the mime type, and a function keyword), and there is also a quoting mismatch. Look carefully at these matters. As @wahwahwah said, use the console to help discover some of these issues. If you're not sure as to what console we're talking about, there is one available with the browser, usually with developer tools. If you cannot seem to find it, let us know which browser that you primarily use.

Comment: How to access the console is [**here**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: *«fucntion»* should `function`. Look for a text editor which highlights code keywords!

Comment: I'll correct the misspellings and see if that helps thanks, also for those of you that correctly pointed out that I didn't frame my question very well, I fixed that in the body of the post.

Comment: Also, I just checked to console, as expected it's having issues with my example.js. Says I have an uncaught syntax error in line 12 but i dont know whats wrong with it. How do i know if jquery is loading? I've never used it before. I dont think it is however.

Comment: @Adamwuh you would see things like `$ not defined` or `$.ajax() not defined` if jQuery was not loading. http://jshint.com/ is your tool to find syntax errors.

Comment: Most of the errors I see come from incorrect spelling of `function`. Suspect you catch all those first and you will do a lot better.

Comment: Ok, thanks to @twisty for fixing all my mistakes. I think you've fixed my spelling errors and syntax. That was probably just lazy on my part. But now It's pretty clear I haven't incorporated jquery correctly into this thing. I just checked the console within my chrome browser and I'm seeing this: 
jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1247 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (example.js:3)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1193)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1199)

Comment: @Twisty I just downloaded the jquery file from jquery.com and saved it inside the /js folder within the project folder. I'm assuming there's more to it that I missed. Any insight?

Comment: Personally I would include it in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Including the jQuery should be all that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your issues are a result of the incorrect spelling of "function". I also found this error:

```
newContent += <a href = "descriptions.html#';
```

You're missing the starting `'`, it should be:

```
newContent += '<a href = "descriptions.html#';
```

With all syntax errors corrected, your code should work:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() { //when the DOM is ready
  var times; //declare global variable
  $.ajax({ //set up request
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { //before requesting data
      if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { //if supported
        xhr.overrideMimeType("applicaition/json"); // set MIME to prevent errors
      }
    }
  });
  //funciton that colleges data from the json file
  function loadTimetable() { //decalre function
    $.getJSON('data/example.json') //try to collect json data
      .done(function(data) { //if succesful
        times = data; //store in variable
      }).fail(function() { //if a problem: show message
        $('#event').html('Sorry! we couldnt load your time table at the moment');
      });
  }
  loadTimetable(); //call the function

  //CLICK ON TEH EVENT TO LOAD A TIME TABLE
  $('#content').on('click', '#event a', function(e) { //user clicks on place
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading page
    var loc = this.id.toUpperCase(); //get value of id attr
    var newContent = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < times[loc].length; i++) { // loop through sessions
      newContent += '<li><span class = "time">' + times[loc][i].time + '</span>';
      newContent += '<a href = "descriptions.html#';
      newContent += times[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
      newContent += times[loc][i].title + '</a></li>';
    }
    $('#sessions').html('<ul>' + newContent + '</ul>'); // Display Time
    $('#event a.current').removeClass('current'); // update selected link
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $('#details').text('');
  });

  //CLICK ON A SESSION TO LEAD THE DESCRIPTION
  $('#content').on('click', '#sessions li a', function(e) { //click on session
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent loading
    var fragment = this.href; //title is in href
    fragment = fragment.replace('#', ' #'); //Add Space before #
    $('#details').load(fragment); //to load info
    $('#sessions a.current').removeClass('current'); //update selected
  });

  //CLICK ON PRIMARY NAVIGATION
  $('nav a').on('click', function(e) { //click on nav
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading
    var url = this.href; //get UR: to load
    $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $('#container').remove(); //remove old
    $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('slow'); // add new
  });
});
```